# What is the algorithm of making a valid CURL URL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

CURL likes to change url's to a "valid" url. And that is not a problem if we used a normal CURL function, but we are using a `curl_multi_handle` which means that the response is in a random order.

To connect a url to a url in the database, we have to check the 'old' url from the database with the 'new' url from CURL.

For example:

```
|----------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| Database URL                     | CURL URL                       |
| https://example.com              | https:/example.com/            |
| https://example.com/file.php/    | https://example.com/file.php   |
| example.com                      | http://example.com             |
| http://example.com/f.php#section | http://example.com/f.php       |
|----------------------------------|--------------------------------|
```

But these are just 4 examples, and there are a lot more cases where the URL changes.

What is the algorithm/method CURL uses to make a "valid" url from a url from user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no way to get the transformation. But you could add to the sent request an information that can be checked in the response.

Let's say we had an header `"InitialURL: example.com"`, and activate the option `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT`. Then, when you call `curl_getinfo()` you could find this information and check the match with your database records.

```
$ch = curl_init('example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('InitialURL: example.com'));
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {

  // get informations
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

  // read the request header
  $headers = explode("\r\n", $info['request_header']);
  foreach ($headers as $value) {

    // Split key/value
    if (strpos($value, ': ') === false) continue;
    list($key, $value) = explode(": ", $value, 2);

    // Find the value or InitialURL
    if ($key == "InitialURL") {
        var_dump($value); // "example.com"
    }
  }
}
curl_close($ch);
```

It's the beauty of the HTTP protocol :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Now we are sure every URL can be found in the database!

Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Given your examples:

`https://example.com` is missing the path; at the very least it requires a path resource `/`.

`https://example.com/file.php/` is technically valid and cURL will not modify this URL.  It's correctness is up to how the remote server treats the `/` after the file component.

`example.com` is invalid and is missing at least the protocol and path.  cURL will add the scheme `http://` and path `/`.

`http://example.com/f.php#section` will remove the URL fragment (everything after and including `#`) because this is client side and must not be sent to the server.

If you're concerned about the validity or URL's, check them when you insert into the database, or run them through [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and re-construct the URL based on it's output.

You can see exactly what cURL will do to rebuild a URL at https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/2427d94c6d088b13ad971bb3cee5b7de42b37d24/lib/url.c#L2435

Ultimately, I'd just run your URL's through `parse_url()` and reconstruct them to something valid before passing along to cURL.